# Не отображается HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В общем, задача стояла такая. 
Вводимые в форму данные с помощью ЖС отправляются на PHP скрипт, который их обрабатывает и отправляет назад, ЖС - вешает ответ.
В итоге HTML - не отображается вообще, в исх коде есть

**js**

```
function reg(){
$.ajax(
 {
  async: true,
  type: "POST",
  url: "insert.php",
  data: "login=" + login + "&pass=" + pass + "&ok_id=" + ok_id,
  success: function(data){
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = data;
  }}
);
}
```

**форма**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
echo 'сессия есть';
}else{
?>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="js.js">
</head>
<body>
<font color="green">
<form action = "" method = "POST">
Придумайте логин:<br>
<input type = "text" name="login"><br>
Придумайте пароль:<br>
<input type = "text" name="pass"><br>
ID вашего профиля:<br>
<input type = "text" name="ok_id"><br>
<button  onclick="reg();">Продолжить</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="res"  class="res"> </div>
Не знаешь, как заполнить то или иное поле? Тебе <a href="faq.php">Сюда</a><br>
Регистрируясь, вы автоматически соглашаетесь с <a href="rules.php">правилами сайта</a>
</body>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Как у вас формируются переменные (`login`, `pass`, `ok_id`)? 

    data: "login=" + login + "&pass=" + pass + "&ok_id=" + ok_id,

Покажите код файла `insert.php`.
Попробуйте сделать `console.log(data)` на `success` и покажите, что видите.

Comment: так же надо проверить наличие ошибок в консоле

Comment: insert.php простой обработчик, приходящих данных

Comment: @Lalka, да тут в принципе у вас нет ничего сложного, но раз не работает, то где-то ошибка. Или решайте сами или предоставьте как можно больше данных

Comment: На заметку: [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: И раз уж используете jQuery лучше сделать не так `document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = data;` а так `$('#res').html(data);`